Probability all three pairs of adjacent cards are more than $1$ apart in difference

A deck of four cards numbered from $1$ to $4$ are shuffled. What is the probability that all three pairs of adjacent cards are more than $1$ apart in difference?

Just want to make sure if my answer is right. I can only think of $2$ possible scenarios when this can happen: $(2,4,1,3)$ and $(3,1,4,2)$. So the answer is:
$$ P = \frac{2}{4!} = \frac{1}{12}$$
Is this correct?

Yes, you are correct.
You can't start with $1$ or $4$. Take $1$: you can't have $2$ second by the rule; if you have $3$ second then the third card is guaranteed to break the rule; if you have $4$ second then the final two cards are guaranteed to break the rule. The same argument can be made when starting with $4$.
When starting with $2$ or $3$ there is only one valid option (as you say). Take $2$: you have to have $4$ next, then $1$, then $3$. Anything else would automatically break the rule. Again, the same argument works for $3$.
So there are only two valid options. The total number of options is, as you say, $4!$ so the probability of drawing one of the valid options  is $$\frac{2}{4!} = \frac{1}{12}$$

I wonder what happens for $n$ cards. It would be way harder to brute force every possible option like I did here so I wonder if there is a more elegant mathematical explanation.

You automatically break the rule if you are ever left with a consecutive set of 2 or 3 cards undrawn. Also, we know how to finish if we're ever left with 4 consecutive cards so that might be useful

I wonder the same. All I could think of is the brute force option.
